# BL460c Gen9 "disconnected NIC", not connect until I reset OA

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, blade-server

I have 3 C7000 blades enclosures that we used with BL460c Gen8 without any problems, but we are changing them for BL460c Gen9 and some blades don't connect it network until I reset OA.

All blades are using 536FLB FlexibleLOM with the last SPP (May 2021), I've tested with 3 OA with different version, 4.97, 4.90 and 4.60.

Also, I used HP 6125G switches and 1GbE Pass Through for testing.

Moving the blade alongside the enclosure can or cannot reproduce the problem, it's random.
Exchange the FLB between blades can or cannot reproduce the problem.
Exchange the blade between enclosures, can or cannot reproduce the problem.

I'm really confused about this problem.

All blades are updated, all have been reset to manufacture configuration, all servers are from different distributors, I think it's not the problem.